# Различие страниц на блоге

Tags: блог

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему текст с [вот этой страницы](https://matematikaandinformatika.blogspot.com/p/lyx-bat-js.html) моего блога доступен для выделения, а текст с [этой](https://matematikaandinformatika.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=APq4FmDl6R81SPeyFBwt8bIHvDKyqiloADSvL0R-rxsUo-U-aBMsfrpF0AlhOoMc2rdnu30HQrStnlmarFCYG8Ai-80kD5atv7aAlHyz_bRuE8vCFu_Bd9_zCToG0DqOd0JCyq55uxk3&postId=8716027890789550449&type=PAGE) - нет? И на той странице, где текст не выделяется, нет карандаша для начала редактирования, несмотря на то, что я ту страницу просматриваю как автор?

Comment: Нажмите правую кнопку мыши, в меню выберите «Проверить элемент» (или «Исследовать элемент» в зависимости от версии браузера), и вы увидите ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: Ничего там не понимаю. Как сделать, чтоб выделялся?

Comment: Ничего не понимаете в html-элементах? Ну, тогда придётся начать с чтения учебников по html

Comment: Да зачем мне это? Я увлекаюсь математикой. Мне тупо нужно выделить текст с моего блога и вставить в ответ сюда. **И все!**

Comment: Похоже это ссылка на просмотр страницы при редактировании, а не на саму страницу. То ли вы страницу редактировали, но нормально не опубликовали, то ли просто по ошибке вставили не ту ссылку на вашей странице по LyX.

Comment: Вот кстати методом тыка нашел нормальную ссылку: https://matematikaandinformatika.blogspot.com/p/lyx-js.html (тупо убрал -bat из той ссылки, где выделение работает)

Comment: Да, я стал не публиковать страницы, а вставлять на них ссылки с просмотра, потому что, думаю, даже после публикации на странице *Навороты программы LyX* помещаются не сами страницы, а ссылки на них. Так это получается, и в этом случае страницы нужно публиковать?

Comment: Сейчас страницу про `.js`опубликовал и все заработало. Спасибо всем.